# Django Queryset Repr Error

Tags: python, django

So I've made the switch from Flask to Django to try the latter out. So far I really like the models in Django, but I've run into a bit of a problem that I cannot figure out.

So I'm making a blog application and when I run the following, I get this error:

> Unable to get repr for class 'django.db.models.query.QuerySet'

Here is the code that generates this error, it happens on the line where I try to pull all of the Category class...

```
class HomeView(TemplateView):
    template_name = "home.html"
    context_object_name = 'nav_elements'

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        nav_elements = {}
        if OASIS_BLOG in INSTALLED_APPS:
            nav_elements[OASIS_BLOG[5:]] = self.get_categories() 
        return nav_elements

    @staticmethod
    def get_categories():
        from apps.OASIS_Blog.models import Category
        cats = Category.objects.all()
        catdict = {}
        for cat in cats:
            if not cat.parent_category:
                if not catdict.get(cat.name):
                    catdict[cat.name] = []
                else:
                    pass
            else:
                if cat.parent_category.name in catdict.keys():
                    catdict[cat.parent_category.name].append('\t' + cat.name)        
                else:
                    catdict[cat.parent_category.name] = ['\t' + cat.name]    
        return catdict
```

And here is the Category model...

```
class Category(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=64, blank=False)
    parent_category = models.ForeignKey('self', null=True, blank=True)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return u'{0}{1}'.format(
            self.name, 
            "" if not self.parent_category else " - {0}".format(
                self.parent_category
            ) 
        )

    class Meta:
        app_label = 'OASIS_Blog'
        verbose_name_plural = "categories"
```

I have no idea why this is happening, and my attempt to find a solution in debugging or poking around forums and documentation has not turned up anything that suggests to me a solution. Does anyone have any clue as to what is going on here?

Comment: Could you show the traceback?

Comment: It hasn't been leaving one. It just returns None to the 'cats' variable; that error message is only seen in debugging. I think I found the problem though.

Comment: This question might need to be deleted. Unless someone can provide a better answer to why this happened, I suppose. I mean just going through this seemed to help, but I don't think this would be of help to anyone else, as it is now.

Comment: If you can figure out the unresolved bits mentioned in your partial answer, it might end up that this problem isn't totally unique to your setup.  I'd propose keeping it around at least until then -- if you're going to continue looking into it.

Answer (score 0):

The problem seems to be that I was directing the manage.py script to the wrong settings file. There are still some unanswered questions. The big one is why I could access the Category data in the shell, but not when I ran the server. It might have something to do with how manage.py is called.

In the former case I would just call 'python manage.py shell', in the latter I would call 'python manage.py runserver config.settings' (I changed this to config.environment.development, and now it's working properly).

Comment: This sounds like an environment problem.  You could try printing (or logging) information on where it was being executed from in both cases and see what is different.

Comment: Sorry, that last comment seems a little weird.  I'm wondering if we can extract the environment variables such as the $PATH in both cases.  I don't know how to do that off of the top of my head but it can't be that hard.